# Windows Phone: playing a recorded sound throws exception

Tags: windows-phone-8, xna, media-player

I am using an `AudioVideoCaptureDevice` to record some sound from the microphone. I want to give the user feedback on what he recorded so I want to be able to play it.

When putting that sound into a Song and playing it via `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer`, I am getting an exception:

> {System.InvalidOperationException: Song playback failed. 
>       Please verify that the song is not DRM protected. 
>       DRM protected songs are not supported for creator games. 
>       ---> System.InvalidOperationException: An unexpected error has occurred.
>       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaQueue.Play(Song song)}

Looking into the details of the song in the watch, the `IsProtected()` seems to cause issues. (If playback works, I get correctly that the song is not protected.) I am using AAC and ACM codecs, both give same results.

I can play the song after closing and opening the view again, but have not found any related initialization that would explain this.

I also tried copying the file, in case some process was still holding a lock on it, still, there is no improvement, same with isolated storage.

After not closing app but re-entering view the song plays without problems.

How can I directly play the recorded audio without any problems?

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer, and also posted the code I changed/added in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the AudioRecorder sample from http://independentinnovation.net/blogs/independentinnovation/archive/2012/12/11/Windows-Phone-8-Audio-Recording-using-Windows.Phone.Media.Capture.aspx .
(Note: right now this link is not working, domain expired.. anyway, I used someone else's code.)

It turns out, that in the Record() function, a stream is opened, that in the Stop() function is never properly flushed and disposed.

I don't understand how this could have caused the problem, since I did copy the resulting file, just to make sure that all handles are valid.

Still, old handling was definitely wrong and new handling is a lot cleaner, and, btw, works.

```
    public async void StopRecording()
    {
        try
        {
            if (dev != null)
            {
                await dev.StopRecordingAsync();
                dev = null;
                // these 2 lines I had to add
                await recordingStream.FlushAsync();
                recordingStream.Dispose();
           }
            var length = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName).Length;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Recorded " + fileName + " with length " + length);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

edit: to give credits, I found the answer I used here http://www.postseek.com/meta/9fddd403d0cde523a542be42b7a4b057

Comment: I'm assuming the majority of that is their code.  Consider setting `recordingStream` to `null` so as to avoid accidental usage of a disposed object.